# Why is $\ln(x^x)=x\ln(x)$ valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

I know that $\ln(x^k)=k\ln(x)$ for any constant $k$, but why is $\ln(x^x)=x\ln(x)$. The exponent $x$ is not constant.

Comment: My textbook uses this equality to differentiate $y = x^x$. (This comment was an answer to a question that was deleted, asking where I saw this).

Comment: How do you define 'constant'?

Comment: $e^{x\ln x}=\left(e^{\ln x}\right)^{x}=x^{x}=e^{\ln x^{x}}$ This
for every $x>0$. Do you agree?

Comment: You have no problems to accept $\ln 3^2$ is $2\ln 3$ and $\ln 3^4$ is $4\ln 3$, but find it odd that it can hold that $\ln 3^3$ is $3\ln 3$?

Comment: @drhab yes, as exponentiation is 1-1 (in particular injective), would you post it as an answer so I can qualify it as such?

Comment: Something being not constant is a problem only if you are taking a derivative. You are not, here. 
When you derive, then you will have to take both terms into account.

Answer (score 15):

As $x$ is probably not an integer, $x^x$ is defined as :
$$x^x = e^{x\ln(x)}$$

Hence, taking the logarithm give you $\ln{x^x}=x\ln(x)$

Comment: "not an integer" or rational number, I'm sure you mean. Though of course this definitions works for those, too, so what am I complaining about?

Comment: @GFauxPas : Basically, for integer, $a^n = \overbrace{a\cdot ... \cdot a}^{n \text{ times }}$. Or at least it is the definition I was always given (while for any number not being an integer, $a^x = e^{x \ln{a}}$)

Comment: This answer is ok, I get it. But I'm not accepting it as an answer because it invokes a "mysterious" definition. In other words, drhab's comment is a much more elegant answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @servabat Yes but consider $4^{1/2}$. But it doesn't matter in this context because $a^x = e^{x \ln a}$ is true anyway.

Comment: @Larede What non-mysterious definition do you use to define $2^{\pi}$?

Comment: @GFauxPas : Indeed.. but clearly you can't use the integer definition for non-integers, that's what I meant by "not an integer" (you can split the cases, but the "non-integer" definition is also valid for integers and rationals).

Comment: @GFauxPas I can define it as the limit of the sequence $2^x$ as $x$ goes to $\pi$. But what I'm saying is that, if you give this explanation in a classroom it would raise a lot of questions and confusions as you use something that not everyone is familiar with, if you use that the exponential function is injective nobody will complain.

Comment: @Larede servabat's definition is the standard, textbook definition of exponentiation. The limit of a sequence definition is much more difficult to use.

Answer (score 6):

The general rule for logarithms is $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$ for *any* real numbers $a$ and $b$ (as long as $a$ is positive).  In particular, it holds when $a=b=x$ (assuming, again, that $x$ is positive).

Answer (score 1):

For all $y > 0$, $\ln y$ is by definition the power that $e$ must be raised by to give the value $y$. So,

\begin{equation}
e^{\ln y} = y.
\end{equation}

In particular it is true for any $x$ such that $x^x > 0$. So substituting $x^x$ for $y$,

\begin{equation}
e^{\ln x^x} = x^x.
\end{equation}

But we also have from the exponent laws and the definition of $\ln$ that,

\begin{equation}
e^{x \ln x} = (e^{\ln x})^x = x^x
\end{equation}

Comparing the left and right hand sides of the above two equations it follows that $\ln x^x = x \ln x$.

Answer (score 0):

For any positive real number $x$, $x\ln x = \ln (x^x)$.  This is a statement about very many "constants" $x$.  It means $3\ln 3 = \ln (3^3)$, $4\ln 4 = \ln (4^4)$, etc.  The only difference between this and $k\ln x = \ln (x^k)$ is the latter is allowed to have $k$ be different from $x$.

Answer (score 0):

another way to think about it, for positive real $x,y$:

$$
\ln y = \log_x y \cdot \ln x \tag{1}
$$
and, again by definition
$$
\log_x x^x= x
$$

Answer (score 0):

For every $x>0$ we have: $$e^{x\ln x}=(e^{\ln x})^x=x^x=e^{\ln x^x}$$
Next to that function $x\mapsto e^x$ is injective, so we are allowed to conclude: $$x\ln x=\ln x^x$$